# Pageable instantiation succeeds in WebMvcTest, fails on running server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm kind of stumped by this one. Both the examples I've seen and everything I've found online says that this

```
public ResponseEntity<StandaloneTerminals> getTerminalsBySearchTerm(
        @PathParam("term") String term, @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 25) Pageable pageRequest) {
    Page<StandaloneTerminal> terminals;
    ...
}
```

Should work. When run in a unit test of

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(TerminalController.class)
public class TerminalControllerTest {
...

@Test
public void getAll() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/terminals")).andDo(print())             
            .andExpect(status().is(200))
            .andReturn();
    ...
}
```

It does!

However, actually pointing Postman at that endpoint results in

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]: Specified class is an interface
```

I've read multiple questions on Stack Overflow on this issue and have tried adding @EnableSpringDataWebSupport to a new WebConfig class as well as, at varying times, to my AppConfig and Controller just to  be safe. Spring continues to refuse to instantiate this bean.

Edit: Application config, as requested:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class AppConfig {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your configuration? It seem it have a problem when spring initialize the bean.

Comment: The app config? I have added it.

Comment: Do you happen to be using Swagger?

Comment: Yes, a great deal of it. We've tried running this with it commented out for that method and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Martin your question turned out to be very prescient. While the problem still occurred with the swagger annotations commented out running the project without the swagger config was what got it to work. Is this something you've seen before? Do you know how to get this to work with Spring Fox?

Comment: Currently there's an unsolved issue with Pageable and Swagger. Commenting out the annotations is not enough, you should disable Swagger and see if it fixes the problem. Currently Swagger and Pageable don't get along well. I spend a lot of time trying to fix it without success. In our case Swagger is not a priority right now so I disabled it. There's a workaround, I will try to provide the link if I find it.

Comment: I think this was the thread. I'm not 100% sure: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/755. If you find a solution please post it here, it would be of great help.

Comment: I've seen a couple threads like that this morning. The issue they're having is that Pageable is not being parsed correctly when generating the Swagger, but  no mention of Swagger causing their endpoints to error out if there is a Pageable object. Based on that thread and my own tinkering you can fix the appearance of your Swagger with ApiIgnore and ApiImplicitParams. I may have to start my own thread on the Spring Fox site about my issue.

Comment: I know it's not exactly related to your issue, but the thread is what lead me to discover the issue had to do with Swagger.

Answer (score 1):

We were never able to figure out exactly why Spring was failing to instantiate this bean, but we found an unintrusive workaround by making our own implementation of Pageable with a default constructor. Thus far we haven't had any luck getting Sort to work this same way.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
@PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 25) Pageable pageRequest
```

to

```
@PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 25) @RequestParameter(required=false) PageRequest pageRequest
```

Comment: This was suggested in some of the other posts I looked at for this problem and I had tried it before. I tried it again just now and sure enough

    "Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest]: No default constructor found". :'(

Comment: @RequestParameter(required=false) please help to retry

Comment: Adding the @RequestParam gave me a distressing amount of false hope because it being null didn't cause an exception and thus lead me to think it had worked! Unfortunately the Pageable was null even if pagination fields are added to the URL. Thanks for the idea, though.

Comment: with Pageable, httpmessage converter won't know how to instantiate the obj and assign value. So please try with PageRequest